# getting a stack trace in Python by trapping an error

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators, traceback

I am working on a large web project (server-side) with some complex numerical algos that I work on at the core.  The whole server-side code has extensive and elaborate error handling to give the UI a "good" feel.

While I am debugging in the development environment, however, it is useful if something goes wrong deep in the computational bowels to get a stack trace to my terminal.  I wrote a small decorator/wrapper like so:

```
import traceback

def dbg(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            res = fn(*args, **kwargs)
            return res

        except Exception as what:
            print("caught trapped debug exception...")
            print(what)
            traceback.print_stack()
            print("re-raising...\n")
            raise what

    return wrapper
```

Then, before calling the numerical routines, I do like so:

```
@dbg
call_complex_numerical_routines(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

The goal is to get a traceback on my terminal, but pass the error back up so the complex error handling still works.

I may be losing my mind, but it seemed like when I had this in a separate file (dbg.py) and imported that, I got a stack trace that went to the point of what failed.  But, now (or in any case), my stack trace stops at the *wrapper*, without telling me what failed inside the wrapper call, like so:

```
File "/home/utils.py", line 17, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/run.py", line 74, in wrapper
traceback.print_stack()

re-raising...
```

How do I get the rest of the traceback to print, so I can see what looks like a normal traceback that tells me what actually went wrong in the wrapped code?

Answer (score 2):

You should `raise` without passing an exception so that the exception is passed through without being re-raised.

Change:

```
raise what
```

to:

```
raise
```

Comment: OK, I'll try that...but can you explain the difference between using $raise$ with an exception, and why that is different from without one, and why that means it is 'passed through without being re-raised'?

Comment: With an exception instance as an argument, the `raise` statement will add the current frame to the exception instance and then re-raise the exception. Without the argument, the `raise` statement will instead simply pass on the exception in the current `except` block without altering it, so that the caller can handle it without having to deal with a frame unrelated to the cause of the exception.

Comment: Very insightful. Thanks.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't make a difference.  My stack trace still ends with the @dbg wrapper, not the failing line of source code.